# Special price tax applied in catalog but not in product page

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.7.0.2, special-price

I'm migrating Magento 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.1.1 and having following issue.

In catalog view products that has special price set are displayed with tax applied. Although, in the product view the same product shows regular price as well as special price but special price is before tax.

In both cases template uses $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) which, I assume should display proper price.

Before upgrade, on 1.7.0.2 that wasn't a problem because special price was displayed the same as in product list.

I'm not an expert here and I believe that I'm missing something. Could someone explain me why that happens and what possible solutions are?

In admin I have following settings (some of them might be irrelevant):

```
Tax > Calculation Settings > Catalog Prices > Excluding Tax
Tax > Price Display Settings > Display Product Prices In Catalog > Including Tax
Tax > Price Display Settings > Display Shipping Prices > Including Tax
Tax > Fixed Product Taxes > Enable FPT > No
Tax > Fixed Product Taxes > Display Prices In Product Lists > Including FPT Only
Tax > Fixed Product Taxes > Display Prices On Product View Page > Including FPT Only
```

Let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to my problem. It seems that was caused by [Mirasvit SEO](https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/magento-seo.html) plugin.

```
Mirasvit Extensions > SEO > General Settings > Enable Product Rich Snippets
```

was set to **Yes** and it was overwriting (already rendered) price block. Fixed that by changing it to **No**.

Hope that help to anyone in similar situation.